# command or script to generate random password from linux terminal

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, passwords

I want to generate a random safe password from Ubuntu Linux terminal.

I just want a simple one line shell script which could generate a random alpha-numeric password.

Answer (score 1):

This is the simple command to get a password

```
$ dd if=/dev/random count=1 bs=8 2>/dev/null | base64 | sed -e 's/=*$//'
```

Comment: Good answer, but you can improve it by describing what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /dev/urandom| tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9-_!@#$%^&*()_+{}|:<>?='|fold -w 19| head -1
```